# calling function from another class: only some code being called

Tags: swift

I currently have this code in a class called `Housekeeping`, and I'm trying to call it in another class named `GeneLibrary`:

```
func addTop() {
        print("hello")
        let balance = 380000 //remove later, arbitrary value for testing
        let username = "kaplan"
        let balanceLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 30))
        balanceLabel.text = "\(balance)"
        balanceLabel.textAlignment = .center
        balanceLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        balanceLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x*2-95, y: 50)
        balanceLabel.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 160/255, green: 160/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 1.0)
        view.addSubview(balanceLabel)

        let genechipImg = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "genechip"))
        genechipImg.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        genechipImg.center = CGPoint(x: balanceLabel.center.x + 60, y: balanceLabel.center.y)
        view.addSubview(genechipImg)

        let usernameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 130, height: 30))
        usernameLabel.text = "Dr. \(username)"
        usernameLabel.textAlignment = .center
        usernameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        usernameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: 80, y: 50)
        usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 160/255, green: 160/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 1.0)
        view.addSubview(usernameLabel)
```

I'm calling this function in the second class like this: `Housekeeping().addTop()`. For some reason though, none of the labels are created, but `"hello"` is printed to console, which means the function is running but nothing was created. If anybody could shed some light I'd really appreciate it . Thanks!

Comment: Most likely `Housekeeping()` is not the instance you expect

Comment: “I'm calling this function in the second class like this: Housekeeping().addTop()” Yup, that’s the problem. Same sort of mistake as here: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Comment: It is not clear where should the labels be displayed? `Housekeeping().addTop()` creates an object, calles the func and immediately destroys it because it cannot be used. You do not store the Housekeeping instance, and you don't present it anyhow.

Comment: @Matt So I can reference the view controller that presents it like this: ``let a  = self.presentingViewController ``                        ``a.addTop()`` but this returns an error saying value of type view controller has no member addTop

Comment: You have to cast to Housekeeping.

Comment: @matt how would I do that? Sorry for the simple questions, I'm very new to this.

Comment: Casting? http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_casting

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to swift, i recommend first reading about mvc pattern, then use this code in the view file and how to call it inside the controller.